# How do I make an insertion into a list of variable dimensions?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a method (or multiple methods, that are called by one) that can insert a nested list, in any shape I choose.  I'm using a recursive method, that is given the indices where it should add the element in the form of a list.  It gradually narrows the insertion by going to the indicated element at each call, and recurring on that element as long as it has more indices.  Once it has narrowed itself to a one-dimensional list, it inserts the element after the element at the coordinate it has been given, then returns that list.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
def layered_appension(self, lst, coordinates, to_add):
    print('List:' + str(lst) + '\nCoordinates: ' + str(coordinates))
    if len(coordinates) > 1:
        insertion = self.layered_appension(lst[coordinates[0]], coordinates[1:], to_add)
    else:
        insertion = to_add
    out_list = self.insert(lst[coordinates[0]], coordinates[0], insertion)
    return out_list

def insert(self, lst, location, insertion):
    out_list = lst[:location]
    out_list.append(insertion)
    for element in lst[location + 1:]:
        out_list.append(element)
    return out_list
```

If it were working correctly, then the call

```
self.layered_appension([[2, 5, 1], 1, [3, [7, 2]]], [2, 1, 1], 9))
```

Would return [[2, 5, 1], 1, [3, [7, 2, 9]]]. However, I'm getting the error, "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable." What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I ended up reworking my code a lot and simplifying it. Here's the new method, which works:

```
def layered_appension(self, lst, coordinates, to_add):
    print('List:' + str(lst) + '\nCoordinates: ' + str(coordinates))
    if len(coordinates) > 1:
        into_lst = lst.pop(coordinates[0])
        lst.insert(coordinates[0], self.layered_appension(into_lst, coordinates[1:], to_add))
    else:
        lst.insert(coordinates[0], to_add)
    return lst
```

Thanks for the advice! it helped a lot.

Comment: Please include the complete error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DIAGNOSIS**

Add one more `print` at the top of `insert` to make the problem painfully obvious:

```
def insert(lst, location, insertion):
    print('Insert', lst, location, insertion)
    out_list = lst[:location]
    ...
```

Output:

```
List:[[2, 5, 1], 1, [3, [7, 2]]]
Coordinates: [2, 1, 1]
List:[3, [7, 2]]
Coordinates: [1, 1]
List:[7, 2]
Coordinates: [1]
Insert 2 1 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(layered_appension([[2, 5, 1], 1, [3, [7, 2]]], [2, 1, 1], 9))
  File "so.py", line 4, in layered_appension
    insertion = layered_appension(lst[coordinates[0]], coordinates[1:], to_add)
  File "so.py", line 4, in layered_appension
    insertion = layered_appension(lst[coordinates[0]], coordinates[1:], to_add)
  File "so.py", line 7, in layered_appension
    out_list = insert(lst[coordinates[0]], coordinates[0], insertion)
  File "so.py", line 12, in insert
    out_list = lst[:location]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

When you try to perform the insertion here:

```
out_list = insert(lst[coordinates[0]], coordinates[0], insertion)
```

You dug down one level too far.  Instead of inserting into the list after the value `2`, you're trying to insert into the `2` itself.

**PARTIAL REPAIR**

First, the obvious change is to pass down `lst` instead of the value before the insertion target.  Second, I took the liberty of changing the function name so you don't reassign a useful built-in method.  Then I used that method `insert` to shorten the actual insertion.  If you trace the results, you can see that `deep_insert` now returns the expected value `[7, 2, 9]`.

You have a further problem in that, within `layered_appension`, you continue to call your own bottom-level insertion method, rather than replacing the existing element.  This accumulates various higher-level copies of the insertion.  The current version finally yields

```
[[2, 5, 1], 1, [3, [7, 2]], [3, [7, 2], [7, 2, 9]]]
```

Make the non-base cases replace, rather than inserting, and you should be done.

```
def layered_appension(lst, coordinates, to_add):
    print('List:' + str(lst) + '\nCoordinates: ' + str(coordinates))
    if len(coordinates) > 1:
        insertion = layered_appension(lst[coordinates[0]], coordinates[1:], to_add)
    else:
        insertion = to_add
    out_list = deep_insert(lst, coordinates[0], insertion)
    return out_list

def deep_insert(lst, location, insertion):
    print('deep_insert', lst, location, insertion)
    out_list = lst[:]
    out_list.insert(location+1, insertion)
    return out_list
```